# row.clone is not working when the datatable bind to datasourse

Tags: c#, datagridview

datagridview dgv is bind to datatable dt.

dgv_copy is new datagridview.dgv_copy is add row to dgv by using row.clone.

```
      my code is
             if (dgv_copy.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvc in dgv_org.Columns)
                {
                    dgv_copy.Columns.Add(dgvc.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
                }
            }

            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < dgv_org.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                row = (DataGridViewRow)dgv_org.Rows[i].Clone();
                int intColIndex = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgv_org.Rows[i].Cells)
                {
                    row.Cells[intColIndex].Value = cell.Value;
                    intColIndex++;
                }
                dgv_copy.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            dgv_copy.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dgv_copy.Refresh();
```

source is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.clone.aspx

Comment: Please study [Ask].  `But it is not working` is a terrible problem description.  Typically, if the control is bound to a datasource, you should work with the actual data not the user's view of it

Comment: ok can add row directly to datatable dt. but in my case i need to add row to datagridview.Is there any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because original `DataGridView` is bounded to the `DataTable` you can create copy of `DataTable` and boud it to the second `DataGridView`.

```
var original = (DataTable)originalDataGridView.DataSource;
var copy = original.Copy();
copyDataGridView.DataSource = copy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you could just do dgv_copy.rows.add(dgv_org.Rows[i].ItemArray)